Using ERC20Upgradeable and ERC20VotesUpgradeable make duplicate call for mint, burn
I tried to write a smart contract with ERC20Upgradeable and ERC20VotesUpgradeable when i tested it, i got duplication in transaction with same hash, i modified as below and now it works correctly, also delegate give the right powervote
My question is the solution correct ?
Override of _update call only ERC20Upgradeable._update not the two of them
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20BurnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20VotesUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SignedMath.sol";

contract TestToken is
    Initializable,
    ERC20Upgradeable,
    ERC20BurnableUpgradeable,
    OwnableUpgradeable,
    ERC20PermitUpgradeable,
    ERC20VotesUpgradeable,
    PausableUpgradeable,
    ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable,
    UUPSUpgradeable
{
    ...    
    function initialize(
        address _feeWallet,
        uint256 _feeRate,
        address _governor
    ) public initializer {
        __ERC20_init("TestToken", "TSSZ");
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        __Ownable_init(msg.sender);
        __ERC20Permit_init("TestToken");
        __ERC20Votes_init();
        __Pausable_init();
        __ReentrancyGuard_init();
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();

        feeWallet = _feeWallet;
        feeRate = _feeRate;
        governor = _governor;

        mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }


    // Override the _update function to resolve conflict
    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20VotesUpgradeable) {
        // Call the respective _update functions from both parents
        ERC20Upgradeable._update(from, to, value);
        // ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update(from, to, value);
    }

    // Override the nonces function to resolve conflict
    function nonces(
        address owner
    )
        public
        view
        override(ERC20PermitUpgradeable, NoncesUpgradeable)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // Call the respective nonces functions from both parents
        return ERC20PermitUpgradeable.nonces(owner);
    }
}

When i use the twos : i get duplicate transactions.
    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20VotesUpgradeable) {
        // Call the respective _update functions from both parents
        ERC20Upgradeable._update(from, to, value);
        ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update(from, to, value);
    }


Best regards

I did a check and this is what I see, the code of _update inside ERC20VotesUpgradeable already call to super._update(...) which is pointing to ERC20Upgradeable.
So If you override _update function and put these inside. It will make duplicate code of ERC20Upgradeable
        // Call the respective _update functions from both parents
        ERC20Upgradeable._update(from, to, value);
        ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update(from, to, value);

The solution should be:
 // Override the _update function to resolve conflict
    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20VotesUpgradeable) {
        ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update(from, to, value);
    }

Logic of ERC20Upgradeable will be executed by ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update. If you use ERC20Upgradeable.update for instead, you will miss logic of Vote extensions.
BTW, you can remove inheritance Initializable and ERC20Upgradeable. It was already referred inside another, you don't need to make it duplicate.

Thanks a lot...

you should ensure that both the ERC20 logic and the voting logic are executed when the _update function is called. Here's the correct way to override the _update function
function _update(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 value
) internal override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20VotesUpgradeable) {
    // Call the respective _update functions from both parents
    ERC20Upgradeable._update(from, to, value);
    ERC20VotesUpgradeable._update(from, to, value);
}


Hello,
Thanks for your response, the problem is i get a duplicate transactions with mint

can you share the details?
